# Apache CXF wsdl2java: WSDL file returned different from the original one

Tags: java, apache, cxf, soapui, wsdl2java

I received a WSDL file from a customer describing a web service they wanted me to offer.

Using **Apache CXF 3.0.4** and **wsdl2java** the WSDL file was translated into fully annotated Java code from which I implemented the service.

Everything went well until the customer started testing the service using the WSDL file returned from my server via a URL of the following pattern:

```
http://never.mind/SomeService?wsdl
```

When this WSDL URL is loaded in SoapUI I see request XML looking similar to this:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:wsdl="http://wsdl.customer.stuff" xmlns:som="http://other.customer.stuff/xsd/SomeServiceRequest">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <wsdl:SomeService>
         <wsdl:SomeServiceRequest>
            <som:user>?</som:user>
            <som:pw>?</som:pw>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <som:phone>?</som:phone>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <som:start>?</som:start>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <som:end>?</som:end>
            <som:trans>?</som:trans>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <som:protocol>?</som:protocol>
         </wsdl:SomeServiceRequest>
      </wsdl:SomeService>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

But when I load the original WSDL file received from the customer in SoapUI I see request XML similar to this:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:wsdl="http://wsdl.customer.stuff" xmlns:som="http://other.customer.stuff/xsd/SomeServiceRequest">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <wsdl:SomeService>
         <som:SomeServiceRequest>
            <som:user>?</som:user>
            <som:pw>?</som:pw>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <som:phone>?</som:phone>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <som:start>?</som:start>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <som:end>?</som:end>
            <som:trans>?</som:trans>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <som:protocol>?</som:protocol>
         </som:SomeServiceRequest>
      </wsdl:SomeService>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

The big difference is that the `SomeServiceRequest` tag is wrongly prefixed with `wsdl` in the first request structure whereas it is correctly prefixed with `som` in the second.

Does anyone have any idea why the namespace of the `SomeServiceRequest` changes?

---

Here is how the WSDL file I received from the customer looks (I have done a few renamings to censor out customer details):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<s0:definitions name="SomeServiceWsDefinitions" targetNamespace="http://wsdl.customer.stuff" xmlns="" xmlns:s0="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:s1="http://wsdl.customer.stuff" xmlns:s2="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/">
  <s0:types>
    <xs:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://other.customer.stuff/xsd/SomeServiceRequest" xmlns="http://other.customer.stuff/xsd/SomeServiceRequest" xmlns:s0="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:s1="http://wsdl.customer.stuff"
    xmlns:s2="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
      <xs:element name="SomeServiceRequest" type="SomeServiceRequestType" />
      <xs:complexType name="SomeServiceRequestType">
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="user" type="xs:string" />
          <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="pw" type="xs:string" />
          <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="phone" type="xs:string" />
          <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="start" type="xs:long" />
          <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="end" type="xs:long" />
          <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="trans" type="xs:string" />
          <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="protocol" type="xs:string" />
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:complexType>
    </xs:schema>
    <xsd:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://other.customer.stuff/soap/well" xmlns:well="http://other.customer.stuff/soap/well" xmlns:s0="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:s1="http://wsdl.customer.stuff" xmlns:s2="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
      <xsd:element name="ResponseControl" type="well:ResponseControlType" />
      <xsd:complexType name="SomeServiceDataType">
        <xsd:sequence>
          <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="serviceId" type="xsd:int" />
          <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="serviceName" type="xsd:string" />
          <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="tariff" type="xsd:int" />
          <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="status" type="xsd:string" />
          <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="activation" type="xsd:long" />
          <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="cancellation" type="xsd:long" />
          <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="type" type="xsd:string" />
          <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="protocol" type="xsd:string" />
          <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="provider" type="xsd:string" />
        </xsd:sequence>
      </xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:complexType name="ResponseControlType">
        <xsd:sequence>
          <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="code" type="xsd:string" />
          <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="reason" type="xsd:string" />
          <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="detail" type="xsd:string" />
          <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="trans" type="xsd:string" />
        </xsd:sequence>
      </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:schema>
    <xs:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://other.customer.stuff/xsd/SomeServiceResponse" xmlns="http://other.customer.stuff/xsd/SomeServiceResponse" xmlns:ctrl="http://other.customer.stuff/soap/well" xmlns:s0="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
    xmlns:s1="http://wsdl.customer.stuff" xmlns:s2="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
      <xs:import namespace="http://other.customer.stuff/soap/well" />
      <xs:element name="SomeServiceResponse" type="SomeServiceResponseType" />
      <xs:complexType name="SomeServiceResponseType">
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element name="responseControl" type="ctrl:ResponseControlType" />
          <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="SomeServiceData" type="ctrl:SomeServiceDataType" />
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:complexType>
    </xs:schema>
    <xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://wsdl.customer.stuff" xmlns:s0="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:s1="http://wsdl.customer.stuff" xmlns:s2="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
      <xs:import namespace="http://other.customer.stuff/xsd/SomeServiceRequest" />
      <xs:import namespace="http://other.customer.stuff/xsd/SomeServiceResponse" />
      <xs:element name="SomeService">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element ref="env:SomeServiceRequest" xmlns:env="http://other.customer.stuff/xsd/SomeServiceRequest" />
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
      <xs:element name="SomeServiceResponse">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element ref="env:SomeServiceResponse" xmlns:env="http://other.customer.stuff/xsd/SomeServiceResponse" />
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
    </xs:schema>
  </s0:types>
  <s0:message name="SomeService">
    <s0:part element="s1:SomeService" name="parameters" />
  </s0:message>
  <s0:message name="SomeServiceResponse">
    <s0:part element="s1:SomeServiceResponse" name="parameters" />
  </s0:message>
  <s0:portType name="SomeServiceWs">
    <s0:operation name="SomeService" parameterOrder="parameters">
      <s0:input message="s1:SomeService" />
      <s0:output message="s1:SomeServiceResponse" />
    </s0:operation>
  </s0:portType>
  <s0:binding name="SomeServiceWsSoapBinding" type="s1:SomeServiceWs">
    <s2:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />
    <s0:operation name="SomeService">
      <s2:operation soapAction="" style="document" />
      <s0:input>
        <s2:body parts="parameters" use="literal" />
      </s0:input>
      <s0:output>
        <s2:body parts="parameters" use="literal" />
      </s0:output>
    </s0:operation>
  </s0:binding>
  <s0:service name="SomeServiceWs">
    <s0:port binding="s1:SomeServiceWsSoapBinding" name="SomeService">
      <s2:address location="http://never.mind/SomeService" />
    </s0:port>
  </s0:service>
</s0:definitions>
```

---

And this is how the WSDL I retrieve from my service looks:

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:ns1="http://wsdl.customer.stuff" name="SomeServiceWs" targetNamespace="http://wsdl.customer.stuff">
  <wsdl:types>
    <xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:ns3="http://other.customer.stuff/xsd/SomeServiceResponse" xmlns:ns1="http://other.customer.stuff/xsd/SomeServiceRequest" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://wsdl.customer.stuff"
    version="1.0">
      <xs:import namespace="http://other.customer.stuff/xsd/SomeServiceRequest" />
      <xs:import namespace="http://other.customer.stuff/soap/well" />
      <xs:import namespace="http://other.customer.stuff/xsd/SomeServiceResponse" />
      <xs:element name="SomeService">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="SomeServiceRequest" type="ns1:SomeServiceRequestType" />
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
      <xs:element name="SomeServiceResponse">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="SomeServiceResponse" type="ns3:SomeServiceResponseType" />
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
    </xs:schema>
    <xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:tns="http://other.customer.stuff/xsd/SomeServiceResponse" xmlns:ns1="http://other.customer.stuff/soap/well" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://other.customer.stuff/xsd/SomeServiceResponse"
    version="1.0">
      <xs:import namespace="http://other.customer.stuff/soap/well" />
      <xs:element name="SomeServiceResponse" type="tns:SomeServiceResponseType" />
      <xs:complexType name="SomeServiceResponseType">
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element name="responseControl" type="ns1:ResponseControlType" />
          <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="SomeServiceData" type="ns1:SomeServiceDataType" />
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:complexType>
    </xs:schema>
    <xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:tns="http://other.customer.stuff/xsd/SomeServiceRequest" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://other.customer.stuff/xsd/SomeServiceRequest" version="1.0">
      <xs:element name="SomeServiceRequest" type="tns:SomeServiceRequestType" />
      <xs:complexType name="SomeServiceRequestType">
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element name="user" type="xs:string" />
          <xs:element name="pw" type="xs:string" />
          <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="phone" type="xs:string" />
          <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="start" type="xs:long" />
          <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="end" type="xs:long" />
          <xs:element name="trans" type="xs:string" />
          <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="protocol" type="xs:string" />
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:complexType>
    </xs:schema>
    <xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:tns="http://other.customer.stuff/soap/well" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://other.customer.stuff/soap/well" version="1.0">
      <xs:element name="ResponseControl" type="tns:ResponseControlType" />
      <xs:complexType name="ResponseControlType">
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element name="code" type="xs:string" />
          <xs:element name="reason" type="xs:string" />
          <xs:element name="detail" type="xs:string" />
          <xs:element name="trans" type="xs:string" />
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:complexType>
      <xs:complexType name="SomeServiceDataType">
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element name="serviceId" type="xs:int" />
          <xs:element name="serviceName" type="xs:string" />
          <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="tariff" type="xs:int" />
          <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="status" type="xs:string" />
          <xs:element name="activation" type="xs:long" />
          <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="cancellation" type="xs:long" />
          <xs:element name="type" type="xs:string" />
          <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="protocol" type="xs:string" />
          <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="provider" type="xs:string" />
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:complexType>
    </xs:schema>
  </wsdl:types>
  <wsdl:message name="SomeService">
    <wsdl:part element="ns1:SomeService" name="parameters">
    </wsdl:part>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="SomeServiceResponse">
    <wsdl:part element="ns1:SomeServiceResponse" name="parameters">
    </wsdl:part>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:portType name="SomeServiceWs">
    <wsdl:operation name="SomeService">
      <wsdl:input message="ns1:SomeService" name="SomeService">
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output message="ns1:SomeServiceResponse" name="SomeServiceResponse">
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:portType>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

Comment: the tags `<ste:param1>` and `<ste:param2>` are closed with the wrong namespace on both requests, I suppose this is a typo, anyways the problem surely comes from the request schema referenced on the wsdl which seems that one generated with `wsdl2java` (`http://myserver.com/service?wsdl`) strangely is different than to the original, due can you share the `wsdl`?. `:)`

Comment: @albciff: Yes, you are right, those recs were spelling mistakes ;) I have now added the (slightly edited) customer WSDL file and updated the request structures etc. accordingly. Thanks a lot for helping.

Comment: your second request fits correctly the wsdl which you show in your question  since `<xs:element name="SomeService">` is defined in `http://wsdl.customer.stuff` namespace and  `<xs:element name="SomeServiceRequest" type="SomeServiceRequestType" />` is defined in `http://other.customer.stuff/xsd/SomeServiceRequest` namespace. Then probably the `wsdl` you generate using `wsdl2java` in `http://never.mind/SomeService?wsdl` differs from this one... probably you already know this, anyway did you check it?. Sorry if this doesn't help you at all `:)`.

Comment: But I have no influence on the WSDL being generated, do I? I mean, that is taken care of by Apache CXF?

Comment: For comparison I have now also pasted in the WSDL returned by my service.

Comment: the wsdl from your service url seems also well formed (an equal  to first wsdl) in both elements (SomeService and SomeServiceRequest), I don't know why SOAPUI is interpreting differently that the first wsdl `:(`.

Comment: I have no idea either... gosh, I'm lost :/ But thanks a lot for having a look.

Comment: @albciff: Do you happen to know how I can make my service return the original WSDL instead of the Apache CXF digested one? :) (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29527257/apache-cxf-wsdl2java-make-service-return-original-wsdl-file)

Comment: could you please post the parameters you are using for *wsdl2java*?

Comment: @kristu: I have something similar to this in my pom file: `<build><plugins><plugin><groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId><artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId><version>3.0.4</version><executions><execution><id>generate-sources</id><phase>generate-sources</phase><goals><goal>wsdl2java</goal></goals><configuration><wsdlOptions><wsdlOption><wsdl>${basedir}/src/main/resources/soap/never/mind/SomeService.wsdl</wsdl><wsdlLocation>classpath:soap/never/mind/SomeService.wsdl</wsdlLocation></wsdlOption></wsdlOptions></configuration></execution></executions></plugin></plugins></build>`