# Apache CXF wsdl2java: make service return original WSDL file

Tags: java, apache, wsdl, cxf, wsdl2java

I am struggling big time offering a web service based on some WSDL file received from a customer. As described in details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29500064/apache-cxf-wsdl2java-wsdl-file-returned-different-from-the-original-one), the WSDL file returned when appending a `?wsdl` to the service URL like

```
http://never.mind/SomeService?wsdl
```

seems to be misinterpreted by SoapUI and this again prevents the customer from using the service!

I was now hoping that someone could help me understand if it is possible to make the get WSDL endpoint return the original WSDL file instead of some **Apache CXF** digested version?

***Update***: I just read somewhere that there is a WSDLGetInterceptor taking care of the get WSDL requests - can I maybe override that one?

Comment: What is the exact issue being faced while using it in the soapUI? Any logs?

Comment: All the details are described in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29500064/apache-cxf-wsdl2java-wsdl-file-returned-different-from-the-original-one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I chose to override the `getDocument` method of the `WSDLGetUtils` class being used by the `WSDLGetInterceptor`. My version of the utils class `MyWSDLGetUtils`is put into action via this interceptor:

```
public class WsdlGetSoapInterceptor extends AbstractSoapInterceptor {
    public WsdlGetSoapInterceptor() {
        super(Phase.READ);
        addBefore(WSDLGetInterceptor.class.getName());
    }

    /** {@inheritDoc} */
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(final SoapMessage message) throws Fault {
        message.setContextualProperty(WSDLGetUtils.class.getName(), MyWSDLGetUtils.Instance);
    }
}
```